# Invoke Java code having some UI with PHP exec

Tags: java, php, exec, php-java-bridge

In order to do certain functionality I have to invoke Java using PHP exec.

When used in shell directly, it works well. But it throws error related to UI when used with PHP exec.

Albeit reason is quite obvious since UI is not triggered error has been thrown. Is there any way to suppress those errors?

Here is a small Java code which involves some UI:-

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
public class Frame2 extends JFrame 
{
  JPanel pane = new JPanel();
  JButton pressme = new JButton("Press Me");
  Frame2()        // the frame constructor
  {
    super("JPrompt Demo"); setBounds(100,100,300,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container con = this.getContentPane(); // inherit main frame
    con.add(pane);    // JPanel containers default to FlowLayout
    pressme.setMnemonic('P'); // associate hotkey to button
    pane.add(pressme); pressme.requestFocus();
    setVisible(true); // make frame visible
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception  
  {new Frame2();}
}
```

When executed directly in command prompt **javac Frame2.java** it executes without any complaint. But when invoked via PHP exec **exec("javac Frame2.java && java Frame2");** it throws following error:-

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:  No X11 DISPLAY
>   variable was set, but this program performed an operation which
>   requires it.  at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
>     at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536)  at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)     at
>   javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:233)    at
>   Frame2.(Frame2.java:10)     at Frame2.main(Frame2.java:18)

PS - I read a lot about PHP Java Bridge but I would be great if PHP Java Bridge can be avoided.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure its javac that crashes? Please provide the complete stacktrace

Comment: I am sure because when I executes on command line it doesnt give any error. However when I execute it with PHP it throws error. I have modified my question to have entire stack trace. Thanks

Comment: Where do you think the Java UI is going to be shown? This code will not display at a client. As you can see from the stack trace it's trying to display it on your server.

Comment: @SteveC - Thats correct Steve. Thats what I have written, is there any way to get the things working in normal way and suppress the UI? Point is I have some Java code which loads certain configuration files and some bootstrapping which I need, but I dont want UI.

Comment: Again, ` javac Frame2.java ` is the command to compile some java code, not to execute it. Do you mean `java Frame2`?

Comment: @GyroGearless - Yes, I should have been more clear. I have modified PHP exec to reflect that.